# Visual Studio .Net Target Framework Version is grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to open a C++ CLI project and I want it to target .NET 4.5. My installed .NET version is 4.7. But I cannot edit the project's target framework because it is grayed out.

[image: Grayed out target framework version]

I have tried to directly edit the project's file in notepad but I couldn't find where the target framework is defined.

Below is part of the screenshot of the .vcxproj file

[image: Project file xml screenshot]

Comment: Visual Studio says that "This only applies if common language runtime support is set", which is already set above the target framework version row.

Comment: That was the framework version you selected when you created the project.  The IDE does not support editing it, some plumbing is missing to get the References node properly updated.  But you can change it by hand.  Close the solution and use a text editor (Notepad will do) to modify the .vcxproj file.  Locate the PropertyGroup labelled "Globals", change the TargetFrameworkVersion.

Comment: There is no TargetFrameworkVersion nor "Global" label in the .vcxproj file.

Comment: I Changed ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" in App.config but it doesn't work. During compile time it still use .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cpp, which I don't understand.

Comment: So is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, select your project. On the menu bar, open the Project menu and choose Unload project. This unloads the project (.vcxproj) file for your project.

Comment: And then do what?  Do we need to manually edit the csproj file?

Answer (score 2):

To complete Hao Peng's answer.

1. Right click on project.
2. Select "Unload Project"
3. Right click on unloaded project.
4. Select "Edit *.vcxproj"
5. Modify the "TargetFrameworkVersion" tag from "v4.7" to "v4.5"
6. Save and close the file
7. Right click on unloaded project
8. Select "Reload Project"

This feels a bit hacky; nevertheless, it worked for me. I moved from 4.5.2 to 4.5.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this issue, while doing migration from .netframework to .net core.

I have multiple projects in my solution, of which base project was created with output type as Class Library and Target framework is set to '.net5.0-windows' by a tool and the other projects are created as '.netstandard 2.0'. Though the dependent projects are configured correctly in .csproj, the option in the properties is grayed out.

However, when I changed base project targetframework to '.netstandard 2.0' then the Target framework has all installed '.netstandard' versions for rest of the projects.